# Google Sheets: How can I turn an input into a value?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am trying to figure out how to turn an input into a value?

For example:

Someone enters `N/A` in a cell in one column. I want it to appear as a `0` in the next column.

What can be done?

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
=INDEX(IF(ISERR(P2:P8-O2:O8),0,P2:P8-O2:O8))
```

[image]

*(Please adjust ranges to your needs. If still an issue please share more info.)*

Functions used:

- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`ISERR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093348)

Comment: Hi Marikamitsos, One cell has "N/A", but the next column says "#VALUE!".  This is after I try to minus the value from another column.

Comment: We need more info.  Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Hi Marikamitsos, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dSjGLXTv_FII-pmOx-mdlGUPqAkH4609xbJhzznyaZs/edit#gid=1612644763

Comment: Please make your sheet public.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RzSV_JkMlHOxA46L4AsGr-8JbnfcH2fc-QQdvzW9wOA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Okay, the permission has been changed. Done!